# Git clone using public private keys

Tags: git, github, private-key, public-key, git-clone

I have been trying for ages to clone a git repository using public and private keys for authentication instead of password. I generated my keys using puttygen on windows. I cannot log in from windows or from linux. I keep getting the following error:

> git clone [git repo directory]
>
> Cloning into papers...
>
> Enter passphrase for key '/.ssh/id_dsa':
>
> Permission denied (publickey).

I first created my private key with a passphrase, but that didn't work, after I resaved the private key without a passphrase (using puttygen) but it still didn't work.

How do I fix this problem? I have been trying to work it out for so long but now am just totally stuck.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're going to have to explain a lot more about what you're doing to get much help. What does "clone a git account" mean? Can't log in to what? You also haven't said anything about your public key and what you've done with it that might let you use your private key to access ... whatever it is.

Comment: Did you write your public key in your remote repository?

Comment: I mean like I have a git repository on a server. My public key has been added to that (by someone who maintains the server so there shouldn't be a problem on that end). I want to clone the git repository onto my local system from the server.

Comment: Yes the public key has been added to the remote repo. I have tried with different repos. And tried cloning from both Windows and Linux and neither work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You must to know two things: private key can be created is putty and openssh-compatible formats - and these formats are not freely exchangeable (client-side tool can understand putty **or** openssh only), Linux understand only openssh-type keys
2. You must use on client-side (additional) tool, which provide non-interactive authentication by key on request

**A consequence of points 1 and 2**

**Windows-client**: run pageant, load putty's private key into it (enter passphrase for key). *Maybe* you have to redefine in Git ssh-client from system to plink

**Linux-client**: on Windows-host load putty-type private key into puttygen and export into openssh-key. Save this file in Linux-box as `/.ssh/id_dsa`. Run ssh-agent, enter password once. ssh-agent will use password for key for all requests during session

**PS**: Debug your issues with the help of Github ssh-related docs and testing shell